# Attaching an entity to a Request in Symfony

Tags: symfony

I have a symfony 2 application where I set up a kernel.request listener to perform dynamic url checking by loading a corresponding entity from db.
The entity that is loaded then gets attached to a service, so that throughout the application who ever needs that data can ask the service for it.
Reviewing the code I was tempted to simply attach the entity to the Request object. It kind of makes sense, since this entity is used everywhere in the application, and it's determined by a url component.

Is that a proper way to use the Request, or is it better to leave it incapsulated into a service?

Thanks in advance
sergio

Comment: I attach stuff to the request all the time.  Seems to work well.  For controller actions, just define a method variable with the same name and S2 will take care of injecting it directly into the action.  If any twig templates need the entity then I would also store it in twig globals.

Comment: if you have any doubts of slowmotion your app, just store a doctrine reference, syntax is: `$entityManager->getReference('XXXYBundle:Mytable',$element->getId())`

Comment: @Cerad thank you, but if I attach something to the request wouldn't it be available anyways to twig via app.request ?

Comment: @johnSmith thank you, I had not thought of that option.

Comment: As long as you don't have sub requests then sure, app.request will provide it.  However, doing so unnecessarily ties your twig code to an implementation detail.  Your template should not really care where the entity came from.  The template just knows it is there.  Just a suggestion.